# Getting an error when adding a value to indexDB

Tags: reactjs, typescript, indexeddb

I am getting the following error when I am trying to add a value to an IndexedDB key. The object I am adding is a nested object, but I think I have a flow error. I am using React with TypeScript.

**> adding object to IndexedDB: DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value**

```js
import { openDB } from 'idb';
import { ExternalNestedA, ExternalNestedB } from '../redux-store/app-types/firestoreTypesAndPredicates';

const useIndexDb = () => {
  const addNestedDocToIndexDb = async (programId: string, data: ExternalNestedA | ExternalNestedB) => {
    try {
      const db = await openDB('indexTestDB', 1, {
        upgrade(db) {
          if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('data')) {
            db.createObjectStore('data', { keyPath: `${programId}` });
        },
      });

      const transaction = db.transaction('data', 'readwrite');
      const store = transaction.objectStore('data');

      await store.add({ programId: data });

      console.log('Object added to IndexedDB successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding object to IndexedDB:', error);
    }
  };

  return { addNestedDocToIndexDb };
};

export default useIndexDb;
```

Comment: The key path provides a way for the browser to reach into an object and grab a specific property value. When you create an object store with a keypath, you are telling indexedDB what property to use for id. Here, you are trying to add an object that has no value for this property, `'${programId}'`.

Comment: More specifically, the way you're specifying the keypath using a template literal means the keypath with be the *value* of the `programId` variable passed to your addNestedDocToIndexDb function, whereas the value you're storing uses the property name "programId". If you called addNestedDocToIndexDb passing "abc" as programId, then you'd need to store the value using "abc" as the property name. You probably want the keyPath to just be the literal string "programId" not a expression that expands to its value, but it's hard to tell from your code.